# How to pass data from mapStateToProps to getStaticPaths in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I have already looped the list of possible `ids` for dynamic page and I'm tryng to pass the data from Redux (list of `ids`) to `getStaticPaths`  . But I cant read the value from `mapStateToProps` inside `getStaticPath`. What am I doing wrong ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import wrapper from '../redux/store';

import { util, manageList, reportList } from '../../components/helper';
import { getManageListAndCategoryId } from '../../redux/actions/actions';

export async function getStaticPaths(categoryIds) {
  console.log('categoryIds', categoryIds); // always undefined
  // temporarely make static path data while categoryIds is undefined
  const paths = [
    { params: { id: 'object' } },
    { params: { id: 'service' } },
    { params: { id: 'club_cards' } },
    { params: { id: 'schedule' } },
    { params: { id: 'agents' } },
    { params: { id: 'abonements' } },
    { params: { id: 'price_category' } },
    { params: { id: 'person_data' } },
    { params: { id: 'roles' } },
  ];
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params, manageProductsList }) {
  // const postData = util.findFormData(params.id, manageProductsList);
  const postData = { title: 'asdsadasdsad' };
  return {
    props: {
      postData,
    },
  };
}

const Form = ({ manageProductsList }) => (
  <div>
    dasdsadsad
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  categoryIds: state.mainReducer.categoryIds,
  manageProductsList: state.mainReducer.manageProductsList,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Form);
```

Comment: How is your `getStaticPaths` connected to Form component?

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara it was created according to official [tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes/implement-getstaticpaths)
Just created in form/[id].tsx file as described above